# Client-Server and NO-IP (ruby)

Tags: ruby, sockets, client-server

I am trying to connect a simple Ruby client-server(*socket*) right through [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/)

**Code**:
>
 **server**

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby
 require 'socket'

 puts "Server run..."
 server = TCPServer.new('',5000)
 while (session = server.accept)
   Thread.start do
       session.puts "ok"
       session.close
   end  
 end
```

**Code**:
>
 **client**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'

clientSession = TCPSocket.new( "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.", 5000)
while !(clientSession.closed?) && (serverMessage = clientSession.gets)
  if serverMessage =~/ok/
    puts "connect"
  end
end
```

**Connections**:

[Connections Image](http://www.subirimagenes.com/otros-connections-8281306.html)

***Explanation of the graph***

> **PC1**: Ruby server running on port 5000
>
> **PC2**: Ruby client running
>
> **ROUTER**: Mapping to redirect connections to PC1(*server*) port 5000
>
> **NO-IP**: Configured to redirect connections to my public IP(*router*) port 5000
>
> **VPN**: IP from Sweden, to simulate a  connection from *WAN*
>
> *both PCs are on the *local network*

**FIRST TEST** (*green arrows*)  // *client-server* without *no-ip*

*configure the client with my public IP and port 5000*

```
TCPSocket.new( "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.", 5000)
```

> **PC2** Run the client **=>** connect to the **VPN**  **=>** connect to **ROUTER**  **=>** redirects to **PC1**(*server*) **=>**  **PC1** responds "*ok*" **=>** *takes the same way back* **=>** puts on **PC2** "*connect*" # ***work***

**SECOND TEST** (*blue arrows*) // testing *no-ip* from the browser without *client*

*suppose this is my no-ip address: test.no-ip.org*

> **PC2** open *test.no-ip.org* from **browser**  **=>** connect to the **VPN**  **=>** connect to **NO-IP**   **=>** connect to **ROUTER**  **=>** redirects to **PC1**(*server*) **=>**  **PC1** responds "*ok*" **=>** *takes the same way back* **=>** puts "ok" on *browser* and change *test.no-ip-org* for *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.:5000* # ***work***

**THIRD TEST** (*red arrows*) // *client-server* with *no-ip*

*configure the client with no-ip*

```
TCPSocket.new ("test.no-ip.org", 80)
```

> **PC2** Run the *client*.....nothing happens...# ***not work***

---

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: First I would verify that your domain name is correct: As "test.no-ip-org" was likely intended to be test.no-ip.org". You should also verify that you do indeed want a connection on port 80 for your third test. It seems as though you may actually want to establish a connection on port 5000.

Comment: How long ago did you create your dynamic host name? It can sometimes take a few days for DNS updates to propagate around the world. What happens when you execute the console command "nslookup test.no-ip.org" from PC2 (client) while connected to the VPN?

Comment: hello, the domain no-ip is the correct, and works as seen in the second test. performs the redirect to my public IP and the server responds

Comment: sorry in the **THIRD TEST** 'TCPSocket.new ("test.no-ip-org", 80)' I was wrong to write, is 'TCPSocket.new ("test.no-ip.org", 80)' _edit_

Comment: is the router configured to forward the port 80 to client 1?

Comment: the router is configured to redirect on its port 5000 to port 5000 PC1 and NO-IP is set to redirect to my IP public(router) port 5000